# jekyll 3.0.0-beta error Is a directory @ rb_sysopen

Tags: jekyll

With jekyll-2.5.3 I'm able to run "jekyll serve --watch" to generate my site and preview it. However, since upgrading to jekyll-3.0.0.pre.beta1 I now see the following error

```
jekyll serve --watch
Configuration file: /wrk/git/blog/_config.yml
       Deprecation: Auto-regeneration can no longer be set from your configuration file(s). Use the --[no-]watch/-w command-line option instead.
       Deprecation: The 'pygments' configuration option has been renamed to 'highlighter'. Please update your config file accordingly. The allowed values are 'rouge', 'pygments' or null.
            Source: /wrk/git/blog
       Destination: /wrk/git/blog/_site
 Incremental build: enabled
      Generating... 
     Build Warning: Layout 'nil' requested in atom.xml does not exist.
     Build Warning: Layout 'nil' requested in rss.xml does not exist.
jekyll 3.0.0-beta1 | Error:  Is a directory @ rb_sysopen - /wrk/git/blog/_site/tech/2013/04/24/blog
```

I've checked and I have read/write/execute permissions, so I don't think it's a permission error. If it helps, here's my source and layout (https://github.com/minhongrails/blog), which has directories like _includes, _layouts, _posts, index.html, etc in the root directory.

Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason I needed to move my source files into a "source" subdirectory as specified in the _config.yml. Here's some of the _config.yml that I had to modify

```
source: src

# needed to also update this b/c it was generating inside the "source" dir
destination: _site
```

In Jekyll 2 I didn't need to do this but I guess it's now necessary in Jekyll 3? Here's a Github issue with more details: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3248

Answer (score 1):

```
Build Warning: Layout 'nil' requested in atom.xml does not exist.
 Build Warning: Layout 'nil' requested in rss.xml does not exist.
```

I think the layout should be null, not nill.

Comment: Hey Seth! Thanks for your response. You're right, I went ahead and fixed that, but I'm still getting the error described in my problem above. For anyone else with the build warning, here's the Github issue describing it: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/2712